# Running matplotlib-cpp in Visual Studio

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to use the matplotlib-cpp package in my c++ environment in Visual Studio 2019. I installed Python, but besides that I have no experience of using\programming with it.
What should I be doing so I can plot graphs on my cpp program? why does my VS say it cannot find "Python.h" header?

I also encountered online "CMake" as something that has something to do with it (or doesn't?). Do I need to install or download some things that i might have missed?

Thanks!

Comment: is [this](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp) what you are using? Do the examples work? Don't forget the README in the contrib folder

Comment: yes, it it. It is mostly for linux though... I don't seem to understand how I should apply it for windows (even under contrib folder)

Comment: Disclaimer: I've never used this. Did you do the steps, that they propose for windows systems?

Comment: I did. I get these lines in the cmd - "The system cannot find the path specified.
'cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." What steps should I do with CMake? Don't really know how to work with it

Comment: And all this is installed?
    Windows 10 - 64bit
    Anaconda 4.3 (64 bit)
    Python 3.6.0
    CMake 3.9.4
    Visual Studio 2017, 2015, 2013
If so, then it sounds, like you need to specify the path of cmake